# Output alignment is messed up when printing to PowerShell form TextBox

Tags: powershell, textbox, alignment, output

As you see at the picture below, when trying to print the same output to PowerShell form TextBox, the grid is messed up. How can I fix it?

Tried solutions like `Format-Table/List -AutoSize/-Wrap`, nothing helps.

TextBox print code:
``` $outputBox.text = "``r``n ----Selected VMs: ``r``n" + (Get-VM -Name vm_name | out-string) + "``r``n" + $outputBox.text ```

For extend search: ``` $outputBox.text = "``r``n ----Selected VMs: ``r``n" + (Get-VM -Name vm_name | fl | out-string) + "``r``n" + $outputBox.text ```

***Used double `` before "r" and "n" just here as escape characters**

TextBox code:

```
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,250) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(780,505) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, found the solution.
Just change TextBox font
`$TextBox.font = "lucida console"`